# Use more than one class of state in Cordapp

Tags: java, corda

I try to create cordapp with two class of state (I mean 2 different states), but I didn't find any exmaples of this case. 
I wrote different variants of ClientRPC but still have error, when try to create second state.
Is it possible to implement? 
Does anybody can provide me some examples?

Comment: You need to show some code. Your description is too vague. However, if you have two State classes in different packages, at least one of them will have to be referred to by its fully qualified name.

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: I have just ` api.ExampleApi.createDeal - java.lang.NullPointerException` when I try to create transaction

Comment: @Steve11235 https://github.com/Pe4enable/dkp

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following github repo for a CorDapp with more than one state.

https://github.com/CaisR3/LetterOfCredit

Comment: What about java? Can you provide example in java?